# Tamaño de arrays | C++

Tags: c++, array

Estoy intentando obtener el tamaño de un array con la función sizeof() pero me retorna un número que no es. Como podría obtener el tamaño?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double array1[3];
    cout << sizeof(array1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: porfavor no uses librerias viejas de C `<stdlib.h>`, en C++ existe una funcion para todo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para obtener la longitud de un array tienes que dividir el tamaño en memoria de tu array entre el tamaño en memoria del tipo de dato.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double array1[3];
    cout << (sizeof(array1)/sizeof(*array1))<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Desde C++17 podemos usar `std::size`

```
int array[20][30];

std::cout << std::size(array) << '\n';
std::cout << std::size(array[0]) << '\n';
```

Este código genera la siguiente salida:

```
20
30
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3TB04H7Y7rfhbFkG)

Answer (score 3):

> Estoy intentando obtener el tamaño de un array con la función sizeof() pero me retorna un número que no es.

Te equivocas, te retorna el número de lo que has pedido. `sizeof(array1)` te devuelve el tamaño en bytes del tipo `double[3]`, que en muchas arquitecturas serán 24 bytes.

Si quieres saber **la longitud**, puedes escribir una función plantilla que te lo devuelva:

```
template <typename tipo, auto tamanyo>
constexpr auto tamanyo_array(const tipo(&)[tamanyo]) { return tamanyo; }
```

Si no puedes compilar en C++17, esta versión es compatible con estándares anteriores:

```
template <typename tipo, int tamanyo>
constexpr auto tamanyo_array(const tipo(&)[tamanyo]) { return tamanyo; }
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NCoMwEITP7lMsFIqBFlp6q@KLiJRtDCWQP@IGKuKzp9bqpdeZb76RIZylIffK@aCdNKlXWGs/cFRkGwBWNhjiJeQxKEdWIevgT6gdI5MlN/oGpHcDq3eISIn9nj8oRhrLtVxX5VG0W9cJnDAqTtHteIUzwFdrSbtSwARF79PTKFw91/bWVVAM3N/v0ifGuv47@mFigTbxpYI55w8)</kbd>.

También puedes usar la herramienta `std::extent` de la cabecera `<type_traits>`, que te devuelve la longitud de un array, incluso de aquellos de varias dimensiones:

```
double array1[3];
double array2[4][5][6];

std::cout
    << std::extent<decltype(array1)>::value << '\n'
    << std::extent<decltype(array2), 0>::value << '\n'
    << std::extent<decltype(array2), 1>::value << '\n'
    << std::extent<decltype(array2), 2>::value << '\n';
```

El código anterior muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> ```

Comment: ¿Serán bytes en  " te devuelve el tamaño en bits del tipo"?

Comment: Oops, si. Gracias n_n